# PHP UserID to database

Tags: php, sql, database

First I get the BedrijfID out of the session

```
$Deals = $_SESSION['login'];
$sSql = "SELECT BedrijfID FROM tblBedrijf WHERE Email  = '$Deals'";     
$res = $conn->query($sSql); 
return $res;
```

Than I need to put it in an other Table

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tblDeal (Dealnaam, Dealkeuze, Dealbeschrijving,BedrijfID) 
                                    VALUES 
                                    (
                                    '" . $conn -> real_escape_string($this -> m_sNaamdeal) . "', 
                                    '" . $conn -> real_escape_string($this -> m_sAantal) . "',
                                    '" . $conn -> real_escape_string($this -> m_sBeschrijving) . "',
                                    '" . $conn -> real_escape_string($res) . "'
                                    );";
```

Error:

> Warning: mysqli::real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /

Comment: Echo your SQL to the screen to see what's actually being generated, and you'll be able to see which call is generating the error.

Comment: i think the affectation part is missing, we got your $res, but not the object affectations.

Comment: `$res` is likely an object and you are attempting to pass it to `$conn->real_escape_string($res)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch a row first:

```
$Deals = $_SESSION['login'];
$sSql = "SELECT BedrijfID FROM tblBedrijf WHERE Email  = '$Deals'";     
$res = $conn->query($sSql);

$row = $res->fetch_assoc();

$sql = "INSERT INTO tblDeal (Dealnaam, Dealkeuze, Dealbeschrijving,BedrijfID) 
        VALUES 
        (
        '" . $conn -> real_escape_string($this -> m_sNaamdeal) . "', 
        '" . $conn -> real_escape_string($this -> m_sAantal) . "',
        '" . $conn -> real_escape_string($this -> m_sBeschrijving) . "',
        '" . $conn -> real_escape_string($row['BedrijfID']) . "'
        );";
```